# which parameter in Firefox is similar with chrome auto-select-desktop-capture-source

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, select, screen

Is there any parameter to auto select one screen to share for firefox?

I'm doing automation testing with firefox, but selenium WebDriver seems could not operate the below popup window. So i want to make it auto select one screen.

Just like "auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Entire screen" working for chrome.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvGuL.png]

Comment: I'm *think* this is part of Chrome Remote Desktop, and as such would be Chrome-only.

Comment: you mean firefox does not have this auto select feature?